# Mocking instantiated object vs. class in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Could someone help me understand the difference between `unitest.patch` instantianed objects and classes? I'm trying to mock calls to `sagemaker.Session.describe_training_job`.
I have a function that calls `my_session = sagemaker.Session()` then calls `my_session.describe_training_job()` later:

```py
#my_module.py
import sagemaker


def do_something_with_session(local_session, job):
    return local_session.describe_training_job(job)

def my_function(args):
    my_session = sagemaker.Session()

    description = do_something_with_session(my_session, args.job)
```

If I use the test below, the `my_session` object is a MagicMock as expected, but does not have the `describe_training_job` method:

```py
@patch("sagemaker.Session")
def test_class(self, sagemaker_session):
    sagemaker_session.describe_training_job = MagicMock(return_value=self.mock_return_value)
    my_module.my_function(args=self.mock_args)
```

If I instead do this:

```py
@patch("sagemaker.Session")
def test_class(self, sagemaker_session):
    # Need to instantiate an object for this to work
    session_object = sagemaker_session()
    session_object.describe_training_job = MagicMock(return_value=self.mock_return_value)
    my_module.my_function(self.mock_args)
```

Then the test works as expected: the `my_session` object is a MagicMock with a `describe_training_job` method that always returns the value I set it to.

Could someone help understand what the behavior is here? What I've noticed when is that the `name` parameter of the MagicMock is `Session` when I try to use the class, but `Session()` when I do instantiate the object. Not sure how that affects binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mock is a placeholder object, it does not *have* the mocked methods (though it may know which methods can be called if using [autospec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?#autospeccing)). Every method call on the mock that you do not explicitly provide just returns another mock object.

If you mock a class, and that class is instantiated in the tested code, the resulting instance will be another mock. The instantation is just a `__call__` for the mock, which returns another mock as every call does (and it always returns the same mock for the same call). Similar to the result of a function call, this mock can be accessed via `return_value`.

If you set an attribute on the class mock like in your first example, it is only bound to that class mock, not to the instance mock, so this allows to mock only class methods. The main point to understand here is that the class mock and the instance mock are not related like the class and the instance they are mocking. Both have the same `Mock` type, and the instance mock doesn't *know* the class mock that has created it.

This means that instance method attributes have always to be set on the instance mock, as you have done in your second example. Using `return_value` is eqivalent to that, so you could also write:

```py
    sagemaker_session.return_value.describe_training_job = MagicMock(return_value=self.mock_return_value)
```